# Windows Terminal, just translucent (not blurry) background is impossible?

Tags: windows-10, terminal, windows-terminal

I want to achieve something like the screenshot below (not mine, found by Google image search) with Windows Terminal (1.0.1401.0). Just black with low alpha value.

Setting the [acrylic efect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#acrylic-settings), I can see through the terminal window, but the screen beneath looks blurry. Even with `acrylicOpacity:0`, it is blurry like the second screenshot below.

Setting the [background image opacity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#background-image-settings), it seems that the image does NOT blend with the screen beneath but with the background colour defined in the scheme. That is, if the background colour is blue, and the image opacity is 0.3, the image becomes bluish. No, "Don't set the background colour, then" does not work. By default it is black. So, the image just becomes darker.

Is it that just setting translucency not supported? That seems quite odd, because it supports acrylic effect, which not only has to show the screen beneath, but process the screen to make it blurry. To me, that seems more work than just translucency.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Update:* Starting with [release v1.12.10334.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.12.10334.0), Windows Terminal, when installed in Windows 11, now has native support for non-blurry transparency.

*Previous answer (still applicable for Windows 10):*

Nope, it's not possible. A lot of us are pushing for it to be added as a feature in [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1753).

However, someone did provide a workaround in a [comment on that issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1753#issuecomment-687620711), using an AHK script that lets you make ANY window transparent.

Here is my adapted version:

```
; Toggle window transparency on the current window with Win+Escape.
#Esc::
    WinGet, TransLevel, Transparent, A
    if (TransLevel = OFF) {
        WinSet, Transparent, 200, A
    } else {
        WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
    }
return
```

This requires [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: But that script makes the whole window, including the text, translucent, not just the background, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, unfortunatly it does. But Its the only option we have right now. Other methods of applying transparancy via 3rd party tools will do the same.

Comment: Didn't know the answer was updated. I came here because of the other answer added today, and as you said, on Windows 11, it is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

The code has changed a bit. It works fairly well [enter link description here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1753#issuecomment-1047412503)
Like @Bradely mentioned, you will need [enter link description here](https://www.autohotkey.com/) it is pretty quick to install. Then you follow the directions replace the content of the file with the github answer. What I did is set my transparency to 100, and used `win + ctrl + -` and `win + ctrl + =` to adjust the transparency. It is not as beautiful as the terminal you'd expect from a Linux distro, but it is better. I also super bolded my font, and super brightened the font to help it power through. You can actually read behind the terminal which is great Picture
[image]

Comment: I just tested it on Windows 11 and it seems that now clear translucency is supported.

Comment: REALLY!!! Well I know what I am doing next week, and congrats on the 3000 club